# False crossreference numbering (pictures)

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have a problem with picture numbering. I have normally labelled 12 pictures with the caption option, but picture 12 shows an error.

I insert a caption for pictures ("Slika" in Croatian) and it is correctly labelled as picture 12, but when I go to the cross-reference option I can't see it, and I can't figure out why. The first 11 pictures are labelled correctly in cross references.

[image]

Comment: Does your document contain track changes?  Sometimes that can cause "gremlins" in the cross-reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself. A "Track changes" option from the "review" tab in Word was enabled and that is why some of the numbers did not show.
To fix this problem you have to disable "track changes" and press "Accept"- "accept all changes to the document". Then mark complete text and right click "update field".
All the chanhes should be accepted and all the numbers in cross-reference window now visible.

Best regards,
Tomislav